# SQL CLR for splitting string into two dimensional array

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am new in writing SQL CLR for SQL Server TVF, and try create assembly for splitting string (ex. "1:2;1:3;1:4") into two dimensional array:

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(
       FillRowMethodName = "FillRow_Multi",
       TableDefinition = "field nvarchar(4000), item nvarchar(4000)"
       )
    ]
    public static IEnumerable SplitString_Multi(
      [SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]
      SqlString Input,
      [SqlFacet(MaxSize = 1)]
      SqlChars Delimiter1,
      [SqlFacet(MaxSize = 1)]
      SqlChars Delimiter2
    )
    {
        return Input.Value.Split(Delimiter1[0]).Select(s => s.Split(Delimiter2[0]));
    }

    public static void FillRow_Multi(object obj, out SqlString field, out SqlString item)
    {
       *dont know*
    }

}
```

And dont know how to realize FillRow_Multi method properly. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: what is the input ?and what output are you looking for ?

Comment: read the question pls: input - string (ex. "1:2;1:3;1:4"), output - TableDefinition = "field nvarchar(4000), item nvarchar(4000)" ex. 1|2, 1|3, 1|4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, I've managed :) to create the [SQL CLR split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/split-2d-array-with-sql-clr-function.aspx) which you requested

In the referred tutorial, I have also shared the sample CLR project source

I used such a **FillRowMethod**

**Public Shared Sub FillRowMethod(ByVal row As Object, ByRef Id As SqlInt32, ByRef Col1 As String, ByRef Col2 As String)**

And the main split function is defined as follows
**<SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName:="FillRowMethod", TableDefinition:="id int, column1 nvarchar(max), column2 nvarchar(max)")>**

The first split for rows takes place in the main split function.

The FillRowMethod function is used for column populating. It works once for each row created by the previous main function.
So I split input row string value in this function.

Please note that the function should be developed further for cases where row can be splitted into more than the columns expected, etc.

I added a control from my previous [SQL CLR Split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-string-split-tsql-clr-function-sample.aspx) for preventing null values to be returned by the CLR function. I'm not sure it will work as expected in this case.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was a bit faster :) and create similar SQL CLR function with c#. Test it with solution similar to your previous answer and single CLR shows better performance. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I could not find a way to inform the FillRowMethod about the column separator. I had to declare the assembly as UNSAFE. Is your assembly is registered as SAFE mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnRecursiveSplitString] (
    @input VARCHAR(255)
    ,@Delimeter1 CHAR(1)
    ,@Delimeter2 CHAR(1)
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
        WITH CTE1 AS (
                SELECT substring(@input, 0, charindex(@Delimeter1, @input)) field
                    ,substring(@input, charindex(@Delimeter1, @input) + 1, (charindex(@Delimeter2, @input) - charindex(@Delimeter1, @input)) - 1) item
                    ,CAST(STUFF(@input, 1, charindex(@Delimeter2, @input), '') AS VARCHAR(255)) INPUT
                    ,1 RN

                UNION ALL

                SELECT CASE 
                        WHEN LEN(INPUT) > 0
                            THEN CASE 
                                    WHEN charindex(@Delimeter2, INPUT) > 0
                                        THEN substring(substring(INPUT, 0, charindex(@Delimeter1, INPUT)), 0, charindex(@Delimeter2, INPUT))
                                    ELSE substring(INPUT, 0, charindex(@Delimeter1, INPUT))
                                    END
                        END
                    ,CASE 
                        WHEN LEN(INPUT) > 0
                            THEN substring(INPUT, charindex(@Delimeter1, INPUT) + 1, CASE 
                                        WHEN charindex(@Delimeter2, INPUT) > 0
                                            THEN (charindex(@Delimeter2, @input) - charindex(@Delimeter1, @input)) - 1
                                        ELSE LEN(INPUT)
                                        END)
                        END
                    ,CASE 
                        WHEN LEN(INPUT) > 0
                            THEN CAST(STUFF(INPUT, 1, CASE 
                                            WHEN charindex(@Delimeter2, INPUT) > 0
                                                THEN charindex(@Delimeter2, INPUT)
                                            ELSE LEN(INPUT)
                                            END, '') AS VARCHAR(255))
                        END
                    ,RN + 1
                FROM cte1
                WHERE len(INPUT) > 0
                )
        SELECT rn RowNum
            ,field
            ,item
        FROM CTE1
        )
```

USAGE,

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnRecursiveSplitString]('1:2;1:3;1:4',':',';')
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnRecursiveSplitString]('aaa:111' + char(10) + 'bbb:222'+ char(10) + '222:ddd' + char(10) + 'ccc:333' + char(10), ':', char(10))
```

Comment: for performance,we have to understand the whole scenario.you have not much mention about the real requirement.are you getting data from third party or other source ?which version of sql server are you using.My guess,my script is better than SQL CLR function.But there are definitely better script than this.I was just trying different approach.I mean no need of SQL CLR function here,but again you hv to expain the requirement.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I try parse audit information from text column with structure like "FieldName %column_delimiter% Value %row_delimiter% ", but Value may contain %row_delimiter%.  @KumarHarsh, how I can modify your solution to solve this. MS SQL 2008R2 will be used.

Comment: Check I have edited.But hv you really tested my script with other sample data.There is two thing to note. i) Script work well for all other sample data. ii) Performance is better in real scenario.

Comment: Dont work properly with SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnRecursiveSplitString]('aaa:111' + char(10) + 'bbb:222'+  char(10) + '222' + char(10) + 'ccc:333' + char(10), ':', char(10))

Comment: see split string script are always written keeping certain pattern in mind.no doubts i hv corrected my script,still it do not work in your new example,becasue it has different pattern,so first explain all your pattern that can exists.

Comment: I explain - Value may contain %row_delimiter%. Ex. 'aaa:111' + char(10) + 'bbb:222'+ char(10) + '222' + char(10) + 'ccc:333' + char(10)

Answer (score 0):

By using the same [SQL CLR split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-string-split-tsql-clr-function-sample.aspx), I could split multiple times 
I hope, below case is solving your requirement
The input string value is 2-dimensional
It uses a row separator as well as a column separator to distinguish columns and rows from others

```
declare @inputstring nvarchar(max) = '1-2;5-6;100-200'
declare @d int = 0
;with cte as (
select 
    rowno = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by @d),
    r.string
from CLRSplitStringFunction(@inputstring,';',0) r
)
select 
    rowno,
    MAX(col1) col1,
    MAX(col2) col2
from (
select 
    rowno,
    case when ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by rowno order by @d) = 1 then c.string end as col1,
    case when ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by rowno order by @d) = 2 then c.string end as col2
from cte
cross apply CLRSplitStringFunction(cte.string,'-',0) c
) t
group by rowno
```

Here is the output

[image]

I am not sure about the performance difference by using a split function twice or using a single function which returns all data in the desired final tabular format

Comment: Thanks for answer. I thought about this case too, but keep at mind that single clr function may be more efficient.

Comment: Hello reddto, I added an other answer. I hope it is a better solution since the split is completed in the CLR function itself